# Downloading all files with the prefix from the website in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I have a website where there are 100 links to csv files that are automatically downloaded after clicking. Each of the files has a prefix in the form `aaa_`.
The following standard code allows you to save a file based on the URL to the selected location on the disk:

```
Sub Download_from_website()

Dim myURL As String
myURL = "https://mysite/2500/csv/aaa_1.csv"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
WinHttpReq.Send

myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile ("C:\Users\tkp\Desktop\download_from_website\aaa_1.csv")
    oStream.Close
End If

End Sub
```

How can you transform the above code so that you can automatically search the web page to find all links in which the string `aaa_` appears and automatically save in the selected location? I will be very grateful for any tips.

The above code was a simplified example of what I would like to get. However, in fact I would like to save all the files that have the `SEB_` prefix from the site
https://sebgroup.lu/private/luxembourg-based-funds/download-of-portfolio-holdings

Comment: Please share enough HTML that we can ascertain how to get the file links.

Comment: I updated the entry.

Comment: We need to see the HTML to be able to use getElementsByClassname or getElementByID. With either you can extract the .csv file names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should manage them

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
    ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
    ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr _
    ) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
                             Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
                             ByVal pCaller As Long, _
                             ByVal szURL As String, _
                             ByVal szFileName As String, _
                             ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
                             ByVal lpfnCB As Long _
                             ) As Long  
#End If

Public Const BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION As Long = &H10

Public Sub GetLinks()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://sebgroup.lu/private/luxembourg-based-funds/download-of-portfolio-holdings", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Dim list As Object, i As Long
        Set list = html.getElementsByClassName("linklist")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
        For i = 0 To list.Length - 1
            If instr(list(i).getAttribute("href"),"SEB_") > 0 Then
                downloadfile list(i).getAttribute("href")
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub downloadfile(ByVal url As String)
    Dim fileName As String, fileNames() As String, folderName As String
    fileNames = Split(url, "/")
    fileName = fileNames(UBound(fileNames))
    folderName = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\CurrentDownloads\" & fileName '<==change as required
    Dim ret As Long
    ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, url, folderName, BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION, 0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the following script a go. I suppose it will fix the issues you are having now. I've written this script considering the fact that you want all the csv files which have `seb` in their links.

Here you go:

```
Sub DownloadFilesFromWeb()
    Const URL As String = "https://sebgroup.lu/private/luxembourg-based-funds/download-of-portfolio-holdings"
    Dim Http As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest, Html As New HTMLDocument, I&, tempArr As Variant

    With Http
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    With Html.querySelectorAll(".linklist a[href*='seb']")
        For I = 0 To .Length - 1
            tempArr = Split(.item(I).getAttribute("href"), "/")
            tempArr = tempArr(UBound(tempArr))

            Http.Open "GET", .item(I).getAttribute("href"), False
            Http.send

            With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
                .Open
                .Type = 1
                .write Http.responseBody
                ''notice the following line how the "tempArr" should be appended to the folder you have
                .SaveToFile "C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\downloadfile\" & tempArr
                .Close
            End With
        Next I
    End With
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft HTML Object Library
Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1
```